# Where can I set the number of rounds of key in crypto++ (AES/CBC mode)?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, crypto++

Are the rounds of key already set in CBC mode(AES-128:10 rounds,AES-192:12 rounds,Aes-256:14 rounds) or is there other way to set the rounds of key?
I've found setkeywithround(), but it doesn't seem to work with CBCmode.
Below is the sample code I copied and modified from crypto++ wiki

```
void CBC_modified() {
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    SecByteBlock key(32);
    SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    prng.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
    prng.GenerateBlock(iv, iv.size());

    std::string plain = "CBC test mode";

    std::cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl<<endl;
    try
    {
        CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of rounds of standard algorithms such as `AES` are **predefined** and I have never seen anybody change it. if you do so, it will be another algorithm and you will not be able to decrypt it with any **standard** version of algorithm.

Round of `AES` are like this:

- AES-128 -> 10 round
- AES-192 -> 12 round
- AES-256 -> 14 round

BTW, rounds of algorithm is **not** related to its *mode* such as `CBC`.

Comment: So the round is already predefined when I set the key, right? For example, this line of code:`SecByteBlock key(32);` already means that it is AES-256->14 rounds ?

Comment: @王濰紳 it seems that key size will be selected when you call `SetKeyWithIV`.